# How to stop word-wrapping in a CSS Dropdown menu.

Tags: css, menu

In my dropdown menu some of the text within the LI's is wrapping to a new line. 
I want all of them to be 1 line.

I have tried:

```
ul ul li {width:100%;}
```

which doesn't work.

The image below shows what I am faced with.

[image]

Comment: Without html and css to look at, it will be impossible to help. Consider pasting an example at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Here it is;
nav {width:905px;display:block; margin:0 auto 20px;top:10px; position:relative; background-color:#4466dd; } 
nav ul { padding:0 0 0 2px;margin:0; }
nav li { position:relative; float:left; list-style-type:none; }  
nav ul:after {  content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
nav li a {white-space:nowrap;display:block; padding:5px 10px; text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font:bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif; }
nav li a:focus { outline:none;color:#4466dd; }
nav li.last a { border:none; }
nav a span { display:none;}

Comment: nav ul ul { display:none;position:absolute;left:0;padding:5px;}
nav ul ul a {width:100%;color:#FFFFFF;font:13px Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:0;margin:5px;}
nav ul ul a:hover {font-weight:bold;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
li {
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

This should stop the wrapping of the text within the li

Comment: you could also set the `overflow` on the `ul` so the 'expanded' titles don't overlap your container.. `ul { overflow: auto; }`

Comment: OK so it's the container the top level menu items are in that is not WIDE enough to support the included elements. Increase the width of your container, or decrease the width of your elements. Only way - also you may have padding or margins throwing this off.

Comment: Can I see the CSS that is  building your menu? Maybe ***then*** I can help

Comment: nav { width:82%;display:block; margin:0 auto 20px;top:10px; position:relative; background-color:#4466dd; }
nav ul { text-transform:uppercase;padding:0 0 0 2px;margin:0; }
nav li {white-space: nowrap; overflow:none;position:relative; float:left; list-style-type:none; }
nav ul:after {  content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
nav li a { display:block; padding:5px 10px; text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font:bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif; }
nav li a:focus { outline:none;color:#4466dd; }
nav li.last a { border-right:none; }
nav a span { display:none;}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3641/discussion-between-extelliqent-and-rlemon)

Comment: I used this code -> border:1px solid transparent; for ul ul a and problem solved I don`t know any other solution

Comment: did you try not adding a border? or simply adding `padding/margin:1px` or +1px and removing the border. (this would effectively mimic the space taken by the border if in fact that 1 pixel is applied once the background is transparent).

Answer (score 2):

Place this on your dropdowns ("Tech Consulting"):

```
{
    height: auto;
}
```

In the case of the issue here,  place `height: auto;` on the dropdowns (ul li ul li).

I am going to guess that your CSS sets a height to the ul li a ("Small Business"). This places the text outside of the defined height.